# SQL Data range using Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, left-join

I have table1 with data

```
Age
10
21
35
50
```

and my query

```
select count(*) as Total, *
from 

( 
select
case

 when age <18 then '0-20'
 when age between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
 when age between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
 when age between 40 and 49 then '40-49'
 when age between 50 and 59 then '50-59'
 when age between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
 when age between 60 and 99 then '60+'
 end as age_range
 from table1
 ) t
 group by t.age_range
```

The result

```
Total   age_range
1       0-20
1       20-29
1       30-39
1       50-59
```

How do I want to see the result like this ( missing 40-49 with count 0 and above 60+ count 0)

```
Total   age_range
1        0-20
1        20-29
1        30-39
0        40-49
1        50-59
0        60+
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the ranges with row_constructor `values()`, then bring the table with a `left join`, and finally aggregate:

```
select count(t.age) total, r.age_range
from (values 
    ( '0-19',  0, 19),
    ('20-29', 20, 29),
    ('30-39', 30, 39),
    ('40-49', 40, 49),
    ('50-59', 50, 59),
    (  '60+', 60, 99),
) r(age_range, low, high)
left join table1 t
    on t.age between r.low and r.high
group by r.age_range
```

Comment: Than you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The key to problems like this is to recognize that a SQL query itself cannot really create rows, it can only return a filtered/pivoted/grouped subset of data that is passed in to it. Instead of using a `CASE` statement we need to turn this into a *SET based query* where your case options are expressed as rows in a table.

For larger sets you could use a recursive query to build the options, or you could construct a temp table or a table variable to store the rows. However SQL Server 2008 introduced the [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can be used to quickly create an inline table variable for use in your query, [Pinal Dave has a simple writeup on this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/10/30/sql-server-beginning-table-valued-constructors-notes-from-the-field-052/)

```sql
-- Existing data
DECLARE @table AS Table(
    age INT
)
INSERT INTO @table (age)
VALUES (10),(21),(35),(50)

-- updated query
select count(age) as Total, AgeRange
from @table t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (values 
    ( 0,19, '0-19'),
    ( 20, 29, '20-29'),
    ( 30, 39, '30-39'),
    ( 40, 49, '40-49'),
    ( 50, 59, '50-59'),
    ( 60, 999, '60+')
) options(min, max, AgeRange) on t.age BETWEEN options.min AND options.max
GROUP BY AgeRange
```

Results:

```
Total       AgeRange
----------- --------
1           0-19
1           20-29
1           30-39
0           40-49
1           50-59
0           60+
```